# how to do multiple array_union and array_intersection in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Let's say I have a pyspark dataframe containing the following columns: c1, c2, c3, c4 and c5 of the array type.
Now If I want to do:
(c1) intersection (c2 union c3) intersection (c2 union c4 union c5)

I can use array_union on two columns in a loop and keep adding a column with the help of withColumn and then do a round of intersection similarly.

How can I do this in PySpark efficiently? Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use a loop, you can just have one big `withColumn` statement. This should also be the fastest option since you only use spark built-in functions.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df = df.withColumn("crazy_set_operation",
                    f.array_intersect(f.col("c1"),
                                      f.array_intersect(
                                          f.array_union(f.col("c2"), f.col("c3")),
                                          f.array_union(f.array_union(f.col("c2"), F.col("c4")), f.col("c5"))
                                          )
                                      )
                   )
```